# spotfire: How to add a datapoint to the scatterplot which represents the average of displayed points

Tags: data-analysis, spotfire

With the Tibco software Spotfire is there a way to easily add a point to the current displayed scatter point which is the average of the other points on the plot?

NOTE for my case there will be filtering, ie I have 3 columns of data

```
myCategory   X  Y
cat1         1   1
cat1         2   2
cat2         10  10 
cat2         20  20
```

So essentially when I filter and select cat1 I would like 3 points 1,1 ; 2,2 and 1.5,1.5

similarly with cat 2 selected I would like the extra point 15,15 displayed.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

NOTE:  I think the OVER() function might be useful to calculate an average.  Also it might be possible to do it by adding a calculated column with the average, but it would be better if I had a solution without an additional column since the dataset is huge.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working toward a solution for this, and because of limitations with what can be done on the x-axis, I don't see a way to make this happen without a calculated column. Alternatively, I do see a way to display the data you're looking for in a different way. Average lines can be added vertically and horizontally with labels that show the value (or not). The point, visually speaking, resides at the intersection of the average lines. Feel free not to mark this as accepted, as it does not provide the extra point you are looking for.[image]

Comment: I have moved on to a different solution but this idea is interesting.  The issue for me with this solution is that lines add too much clutter to the graph. Strange that there is no easy solution for this, looks like the idea of having a calculated point added to the graph would have many applications where data needed to be summarized in one way or another.